# Implementation of printf

Tags: c, string, printf

Can someone please explain to me which implementation of `printf` prints a string correctly?

version 1:

```
printf(const char * s) {
     while(*s != '\0') {
          write(s, 1, f);
          s++;
     }
}
```

version 2:

```
printf(const char *s) {
     write(s, strlen(s), f);
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from testing this yourself?

Comment: None because you implemented something like puts and not printf.

Comment: The whole point of printf is to print formatted. Your code does not do any formatting.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: version 2 is definitely the better option in terms of performance. Both versions do the same thing.

Comment: Please define what you mean by *"printing a string correctly"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both print "a string correctly". They even print the given string in the argument correctly.

If your question is what is the better implementation I would suggest this strongly depends on the implementation of write.

Option 1 is slower if a write call has a large enough overhead or can buffer all characters before committing the write.

Option 2 is slower if write is very unoptimized. For example it just puts character by character on a serial connection. Here you pay for the additional iteration of the string with strlen.

Note that the write call takes the file descriptor as the first argument, not the last.